# Resetting Meteor's lastSessionId without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there any way to reset `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` without reloading the page? Right now I have to use `location.reload()` to reset it but it's creating a user experience problem. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: It is a bit unclear (at least to me) what you are trying to accomplish and what you are doing. What procedure are you currently using? What is the use case?

Comment: @MasterAM I'm making a file uploading app, and I'm using the session id as the value to identify files uploaded during the given session since it's unique. After the user uploads, they're meant to check out the files they uploaded (like e-commerce) so I don't want them to order again, only to find the previous files in the same session.

Comment: I don't understand the approach. Are the users logged in? What happens when a user refreshes her browser? Is all access to the files gone (because the session id is different). Why couple the upload action and the session? Why not simply generate a dedicated random identifier on the server via a method call?

Comment: @MasterAM I'm a noob prone to noobish ways. You're right. Method calls would be much easier to use. I'm still learning Meteor. Hadn't thought of that approach. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
Meteor.connection = DDP.connect('/');

_.each([
  'subscribe',
  'methods',
  'call',
  'apply',
  'status',
  'reconnect',
  'disconnect'
], function(name) {
  Meteor[name] = _.bind(Meteor.connection[name], Meteor.connection);
});

Meteor.default_connection = Meteor.connection;
```

This is how Meteor init a DDP connection between client and server, the full code can be found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87681c8f166641c6c3e34958032a5a070aa2d11a/packages/ddp-client/client_convenience.js#L45-L71)